# Mvc web app deployed on IIS error : Cannot open database "aspnetdb.mdf" requested by the login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7

I'm working on Mvc web app ,
I have deployed it on IIS 6 which is giving me an error

```
Cannot open database "aspnetdb.mdf" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ASP.NET v4.0'.

I also enable authentication :
anonymous and also for ASP.NET Impersonate
```

My connection string is

```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=True;initial catalog=aspnetdb.mdf"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

please help me

I need to upload this app on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give security access to the database for the IIS App pool identity:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/

Using the SQL Express manager, and the security section.

see this thread:

http://www.justskins.com/forums/sql-iis-application-pool-84726.html

and this

http://kannabirank.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/add-app-pool-identity-to-sql-server-db_owner-role/

Comment: hi Richard I did it all above then also getting same error :(
My database is aspnetdb i.e i'm using sql membership database.
which is in my App_Data folder only